# Using "Like" to find if cell contains a value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare the value of each cell in a column of **one workbook to that of another**, if they values match I'd like to copy that entire row over to the first workbook.

Im setting N as the value that Im comparing and using the "If (cell.Value Like "N") = True Then"

Issue: The is working in that it finds all cells that have the letter "N" in it and copy it over. I need it to find all cells that have the value that I previously assigned to N in it. My code is below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

Dim N as String

For i = 1 To Workbook(1).Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        N = Workbook(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value

        For Each cell In Workbook(2).Sheets(2).Range("B:B").Cells
            If (cell.Value Like "*N*" Then) = True Then
                'Do something; ie, copy over row
            End If
        Next cell
Next i

Workbook(2).Close

End Sub()
```

Comment: You're comparing to the literal value `'*N*'`. You want `Like "*" & N & "*"` instead.

Comment: Try: `If InStr(1, cell.Value2, N, vbTextCompare) Then`

Comment: @KenWhite I attempted this but again it coped over all cells with the value N in it.

Comment: Then your question is very unclearly stated. Can you [edit] to make it more clear what you mean by *Im setting the value that Im comparing to N*?

Comment: @KenWhite in my code there is " N = Workbook(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value"

N is a value in the first work book. In the For loop N is a new value each time.

Comment: Then why are you using LIKE at all? You want the cell's value to match the current value of `N`, so just compare them directly. `If (Cell.Value = N)` will do exactly what it appears you want. If `N  = 1`, then `if (Cell.Value = N)` will match cells that are equal to 1. Then `N = N + 1` means N = 2, and `if (Cell.Value = N)` will match cells that are equal to 2. The only time you need LIKE with wildcards is if you're looking for something similar, as in `N = "cat"` and then `if (Cell.Value LIKE "*" & N & "*") = True)` will match cells with the value *cat*, *category*, *calalog*, *obfuscate*.

Comment: @KenWhite Im using LIKE because cell.Value contains but does not equal N. For example: cell.Value might be 449U-01 and N might be 449. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks("Book1")
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("Book2")

Dim wsName As String

wsName = "Sheet1"

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

wb1.Activate
Set rng1 = wb1.Worksheets(wsName).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
wb2.Activate
Set rng2 = wb2.Worksheets(wsName).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

Dim cell As Range
Dim found As Range

For Each cell In rng1
    Set found = rng2.Find(cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart,  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        'Copy over row
    End If
Next cell

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong or misunderstood. I just got a down vote with no explanation.